# Android: Using a nine-patch background on a button, I cannot add any padding around the text

Tags: java, android, xml

As the title says, I cannot get padding around the text.

Here's my xml:

```
<style name="StandardButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/nine_patch_3</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
</style>
```

Thanks!

Comment: never seen that before, could you add a screenshot of your button in the 9patch application and with text in it to see the disposition, it might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify paddings through the 9-patch image itself. Draw lines along right and bottom borders of the image. Paddings then will be equal to the size of the lines minus size of the stretch lines (drawn on the left and bottom borders).

Second option: try using 'dip' units instead of 'dp' in your style definition.

Comment: Strangely enough, changing to 'dip' helped, although the documentation says you can use both. Hmph. Thanks, Kon!